# After clicking on a radio button, is it possible to make a new option pop up?

Tags: php, jquery, popup

When the user is browsing my system, the user would reach the page where he will choose a shipping option, which is currently using radio buttons. The list is from the database. What I need is:

when the user clicks an option, which is a picture by the way, not a standard radio button, another option will popup, to allow the user to choose a payment option, which is also in my database. I just need to make it pop up so the user will have two values to pass to the other page, namely for `$carrier` and `$payment`.

```
<?php
echo "<table><tr>";
$i = 0;
$qry="SELECT * FROM shipping";
$result= @mysql_query($qry);
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    if ($i > 0 && $i % 3 == 0) { 
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    echo "<td>";
?>

                <table width="" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="1">
                    <tr class="row_submit">
                        <td height="250px" width="300px"><center><label>
                            <input type="radio" name="carrier" <?php if (isset($carrier) && $carrier=="row[ship_name]") echo "checked";?>  value="<?php echo $row['ship_name']; ?>">
                            <!--<img src="../paymentoptions/lbc.png" alt="LBC" class="picture" width="245px" style="margin:10px"/></label></td> -->
                            <?php echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $row['ship_pic'] ).'"  height="210px"  width="245px" style="margin:10px"/>'; ?>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="row_submit">
                        <td height="180px" width="300px"><p><?php echo $row['ship_desc']; ?><p></td>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <div id='price'> Additional ₱ <?php echo $row['ship_price']; ?></div></td></tr>
                </table>

  <?php  
    echo "</td>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</tr></table>";
?>
```

Comment: look at one of 2 things Auto_focus function or Java_scrip can do it by switching out the content of the html id if condition is met

Comment: i was thinking of a modal, but would that pass the value to the $_POST?

Comment: auto_focus will, i am sure the java would too but i am very noob in java

Comment: Your table-rows and table-data is inconsistent, you should fix those